# Time complexity analyze

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Im trying to compute and analyze this here.

```
public static long double_for_loop(int z){
      long result = 0;
      for(int i =0; i<z;i++){
         for(int j =i + 1; j>i; j--){
            result +=(i*j);
         }
      }
    return result;
   }
```

Need help in solving the time-complexity for each sequence of statements.I want to know the steps in solving it.

Comment: @RomanSvistunov what about the result+= (i*j)? Is it O(N)?

Answer (score 7):

The inner loop will do its first iteration with `j=i+1`, then `j` will decrease and condition fails. Therefore it will execute in `Θ(1)`. The outer loop will execute `z` times, therefore for double for, and the function itself, time complexity would be `Θ(z)`

Comment: My answer is O(n^2).. Im confused about the inner loop. Is it (n-1)?

Comment: @RaphaelArpa, the inner loop only executes once for each `i`, it is computed in constant time, `O(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

For *z =4* the process (inner loop) goes like this :

I=0, *J* runs for 1 step ==> *O(1)* , a constant time

I=1, *J* runs for 1 step ==> *O(1)*, a constant time

I=2, *J* runs for 1 step ==> *O(1)* , a constant time

I=3, *J* runs for 1 step ==> *O(1)* , a constant time

So you have a *O(1)*  which is a *constant time* regardless how big *Z* value is. Some people I see write this as O(4) but normally we just write it as *O(1)*. Generally O(C1) is seen as O(C2) for any positive integer constant C1 and C2. So it doesn't matter if you just write it as *O(1)*. The point is *C* value *doesn't depend* on input *Z* size . The scenario will be different if it was *J=Z* instead of *J=I+1*. In that case the inner loop turns out to be linear *O(Z)* coz it depends on *Z*.

So overall you get  O(Z) for the outer  * O(1) for the inner  part which is an O(Z) *linear time* complexity.